# ajax call to php not working 404 error mismatched localhost

Tags: php, ajax, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm using xampp on my Windows 10 dev machine and when I launch my javascript app using chrome, the browser uses `localhost:8080` as the root directory.

For my php ajax calls, I have to use the fully qualified path to get them to work. For example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/get_user.php",
        data: {email: $("#email").val()}
    });
```

Note that I have to use `localhost` for the ajax calls whereas the javascript root is `localhost:8080`. My php files are stored locally in `c:/xampp/htdocs`.

I want to use a short form url that works on both my local dev machine and on the production website. Something like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/get_user.php",
        data: {email: $("#email").val()}
    });
```

My understanding (and I'm new to this) is that if I use the short form url `/get_user.php` the system uses the same root as the client side app (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/get_user.php`). But only fully qualified `http://localhost/get_user.php` is working for my ajax calls.

I get the following error message when using the short form `/get_user.php`:

> GET
>   http://localhost:8080/check_login.php?password=xxxxxxxxxx&email=drew%40aol.com
>   404 (Not Found)

So the client side uses `localhost:8080` and the server side expects `localhost`. I'm sure this is probably an xampp config issue but haven't been able to solve on my own. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data type to jsonp rather than json. I think you are running into a cross-origin resource sharing problem. A permission problem, essentially. localhost and localhost:8080 are two different domains, as far as your browser is concerned. If your code is executed from localhost:8080 and you give it a relative url, like /something.php, it assumes you are requesting it from the same domain. localhost is equivalent to localhost:80.